# why i am getting 'antd@' error when i am trying to install npm

Tags: node.js, npm

My node version is 16.13.0
when i am trying to install - npm install
i am getting error as :

```
# npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: isomorphic@4.0.2
npm ERR! Found: antd@4.24.12
npm ERR! node_modules/antd
npm ERR!   antd@"^4.16.12" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer antd@"^5.0.1" from @ant-design/compatible@5.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@ant-design/compatible
npm ERR!   @ant-design/compatible@"^5.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Also tried using npm install --force
.. still its having errors and saying socket connection timeout
also tried by maximizing the time .. but didnt worked..

this is my package.json file..

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/compatible": "^5.1.1",
    "@glidejs/glide": "^3.4.1",
    "@redq/js-info-bubble": "^0.8.1",
    "@uppy/core": "^1.13.2",
    "@uppy/dropbox": "^1.4.14",
    "@uppy/google-drive": "^1.5.14",
    "@uppy/instagram": "^1.4.14",
    "@uppy/react": "^1.10.6",
    "@uppy/tus": "^1.7.6",
    "antd": "^4.16.12",
    "antd-local-icon": "^0.1.3",
    "auth0-lock": "^12.0.2",
    "card-react": "^1.2.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "clone": "^2.1.2",
    "d3-shape": "^2.0.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.4",
    "enzyme-react-intl": "^2.0.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^9.22.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "frappe-charts": "^1.6.2",
    "fuse.js": "^6.4.1",
    "globalize": "^1.6.0",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "js-rich-marker": "^1.1.2",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.25",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.2",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.0.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.27.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.10.0",
    "react-codemirror": "^1.0.0",
    "react-count-down": "^1.2.1",
    "react-credit-cards": "^0.8.3",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
    "react-dnd": "^11.1.3",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^11.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-drawer": "^1.3.4",
    "react-dropzone-component": "^3.2.0",
    "react-element-resize": "^0.2.3",
    "react-error-overlay": "^6.0.7",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.1.2",
    "react-flip-move": "^3.0.4",
    "react-google-charts": "^3.0.15",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-grid-layout": "^1.1.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-id-swiper": "3.0.0",
    "react-instantsearch": "^6.39.1",
    "react-intl": "^5.8.1",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-motion-drawer": "^3.1.0",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-placeholder": "^4.0.3",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-sidebar": "^3.0.2",
    "react-speech-recognition": "^3.2.3",
    "react-tag-input": "^6.4.3",
    "react-throttle": "^0.3.0",
    "react-trend": "^1.2.5",
    "react-vis": "^1.11.7",
    "react-youtube": "^7.12.0",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.7.0",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-saga-firebase": "^0.15.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "rheostat": "^4.1.1",
    "rich-marker": "^0.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "styled-theme": "^0.3.3",
    "swiper": "^9.3.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.5.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.2",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.6",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "sass": "^1.43.2"
},
```

Can some please help me with this ?am new to react ...

Comment: `Express`? Why do you need express.js on the front end? Maybe you should revise your packages and make sure you are not accidentally installing backend service packages that you should not have installed in the frontend source tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate `antd` from v4 to v5. You need to upgrade the `antd` package to `5.x` first. See [Start upgrading](https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5#start-upgrading)

```
npm install --save antd@5.x
```

The `@ant-design/compatible@5.1.1` package has below peer dependencies:

```
$ npm view @ant-design/compatible@5.1.1 peerDependencies
{ antd: '^5.0.1', react: '>=16.0.0', 'react-dom': '>=16.0.0' }
```

As you can see, you must install `antd@^5` in your project.